# Are float types "nested" for different precisions

Tags: precision

I am currently coding in a scientific code in python. This code uses several different types of float precision, namely half, single and double precision (using numpy). However, my question is more general as it is not specific to python.

Question: are these precisions "nested" in the sense that any number exactly representable (i.e. no approximation) in a lower precision is also exactly representable in higher precision.

Other phrasing: Do I change the value of a float when casting to higher precision ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure that the answer is yes - at least for IEEE754 standard floating point types. If you cast a variable precisely representing a number to a higher precision type, the least significand bits of the new mantissa will be zero, so the answer to your second question is: No, the numeric value won't be changed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear answer. To be honest, it is also what I thought, I cannot however find a reference for this fact